# Vector field along a map

Tags: differential-geometry, examples-counterexamples

Let $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ be open and $f: U \to \mathbb R^m$ be smooth.

Consider the vector fields ${\partial f \over \partial x_i}$.

I think these are an example of a vector field *along $f$* but I can't seem to prove it.

Concretely: Along a map means that the projection $\pi_{TM}: TM \to M$ of the vector field equals the map at a given point. But I tried an example and it seems to be clearly false:

The projection takes $(p,v)$ to $v$, that is, $\pi(p, {\partial f \over \partial x_i}) = {\partial f \over \partial x_i}$ but clearly, this is not equal to $f$.

> What am I missing? And how can I prove this (assuming it is actually
>   true)?

--

> Maybe if possible you could given an example of a concrete $f$ and the
>   map $\pi_{TM}$, I think that would really help me.

Comment: The projection takes $(p,v)$ to $p$ rather than $v$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f:M\to N$ be a smooth map between two smooth manifolds. A vector field along $f$ is a smooth function $X:M\to TN$ such that for every $m\in M$ we have $\pi(X(m))=f(m)$, where $\pi:TN\to N$ is the projection. Intuitively, $X$ eats a point on $M$ and spits out a tangent vector at its image under $f$. This is clearly the case in the example you give, by definition.

Comment: Dear downvoter, it would be nice of you to share with the community the reason for downvoting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you mean that $X(m)$ is the tangent vector to $M$ at $f(m)$? (sorry for asking but the sentence is not clear to me) If so it's not clear to me why the derivatives of $f$ should be tangents to $M$.

Comment: @astudent No, $X(m)$ is a vector tangent to $N$, not $M$.